# Is it up to the caller or called to ensure to make sure the arguments exist?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic

This question should be language agnostic, but for simplicity, I will provide an example in python.

Suppose that I have a pandas dataframe with some columns and I have a getter that gets one of the columns:

```
def get_dataframe_column(dataframe, column_name):
  # should I check that the column exists here
```

I'm wondering what is best practice. Should the `get_data_column` function itself check to make sure the column exists, or should the caller know what they're doing and make sure they're using it correctly?

I feel like when it comes to python, they have more error checking than a language like C++, so maybe the question does become language dependent?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: it depends

any kind of validation decreases performance, so if you're writing performance critical number crunching which will be executed with predefined inputs - then you know exactly what columns are here and you don't need any kind of validation (it is called [offensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offensive_programming))

but, if you writing public api, which will be used by others and they can supply whatever they want, then it is better to validate any input argument to avoid runtime exceptions or unexpected errors (it is called [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming))

either kind of extremum is rare in reality, usually you want some kind of validation at top level, but no validation at lower levels where you control inputs

for example for number crunching - at the start of process you can validate all frames for column presence quickly without doing any extensive math, then run pure calculations because you know that inputs are correct

quite nice but not performant option is to use additional argument which will indicate whether validation should be performed or not (assuming that validation is expensive), it can be also default value which caller will get in case of missing field, something like:

```
def get_dataframe_column(dataframe, column_name, throwIfMissing = False):
    if throwIfMissing and dataframe does not contain column_name:
        throw exception
```